# Why is my try/catch assertion test failing?

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, sinon

not sure what I am doing wrong but it seems fairly simple in my head.  I have a class that creates a new `Session` class inside it.  If the `MainClass` 's `foo` function throws, `session`'s  `deleteEmpty` function is called.

I am trying in my test to ensure that `thrown` has a `value` and that the `deleteEmpty` is called.  When I have the `thrown` assertion itself, it passes.  When I add the assertion to check `deleteEmpty` is called, it fails but the console has no output as to why.

**MainClass**

```
const token = "12345";
const data = { /// };

const session = new Session(token, data);

async function foo() {

    try {
       //

    } catch(error) {  
       await this.session.deleteEmpty();
       throw error;
    }
}
```

**testFile**

```
const sessionMock = Sinon.createStubInstance(Session)
let thrown: Error | undefined = undefined;

sandbox.stub(MainClass, 'foo').throws();

try {
    await MainClass.foo();
} catch(error) {
    thrown = error;
}

expect(sessionMock.deleteEmpty).calledOnce;
expect(thrown).to.not.be.undefined;
```

Comment: The throw is an implementation detail that gets absorbed. Just test that the `deleteAsset` method was called once on whatever triggers the error, and that it's not called on whatever doesn't trigger the error. Since the error is caught and nothing is thrown up to the test suite, there's nothing to catch in the test case unless you want to change your application logic to rethrow the error (I assume you don't want that). Typo: `deleteAsset` / `deleteEmpty`?

Comment: typo, yes.  Fixed it.   Not sure what you mean though, can you elaborate if possible?  I am already trying to test that `deleteEmpty` is called.  It is in the actual application code but I can't get it in the test so I assume I am not doing something correctly.

Comment: You're testing that it was called on a bad path but you're not testing that it _wasn't_ called on a happy path. So you leave open the possibility of a false positive where the code calls it unconditionally. Not sure what you don't understand otherwise without more information--when you catch an error in your code there's nothing for the suite to catch so `expect(thrown).to.not.be.undefined;` will fail unless you rethrow the error in the app so there's something to catch.

Comment: If the `deleteEmpty` assertion is failing too, please provide a [mcve] so I can run the code and figure out what's going on. Either the mock is wrong or the error isn't being thrown/caught such that control flow leads to the call, neither of which can definitively be confirmed or denied based on the provided code here.